# Send ASP.NET Solution To Someone Else Database Not Loading (Browser just spins)

Tags: asp.net

I need to send an ASP.NET solution to someone else, but when I send it to them the solution won't run (it just spins endlessly in the browser), presumably because it won't connect to the database. My web.config file reads thus:

```
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TechSupport.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Is there anything I need to change in the connectionString in order for the solution to run correctly when tested?

Comment: As per the connection string, "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.\SQLEXPRESS" Is this database available to the user who is running your ASP.NET solution? It must be in his own local machine as per the connection string.

Comment: @ Sanish Joseph I have zipped and sent the entire solution, including all files an folders. The .mdf file is in the App_Data folder. I have disconnected the DB before I zipped and sent. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it answers partially. But that's ok. There are a few things to be note. Firstly, Do that person who is using your solution actually has SQL installed? Simply passing the mdf file will not work if the user at the other end does not restores that into his/her SQL database.

Comment: Yes they do have SQL server installed. Do they need to separately drag and drop the .mdf DB file into the App_Data folder?

Comment: They need to restore your database into their database. 
Use below link to see how they can do it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

After restoring your DB, they need to try connecting to that DB and use those credentials they used to connect to that DB. If they have a user name and password, connection string will change. 

You can replace Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.\SQLEXPRESS with  Data Source=. [dot means localDB]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will do as suggested and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can send you solution to another person. To do so you need to make sure and disconnect your database by Right clicking on the database in the Solutions panel, and selecting disconnect.

In my above problem, it turns out that the person I was sending the Solution to had the wrong version of SQL Server AND Visual Studio.

Thanks to @Sanish Joseph